# Authorization header is not sent in swagger calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using following spring boot dependencies.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I configured Authorization header for the rest endpoint like below.

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = "Welcome Controller", description = "Welcome API")
public class HomeController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Sent secret message", notes = "Sent secret message")

    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Access Token", required = false, allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", dataTypeClass = String.class, example = "Bearer access_token") })
    @GetMapping("/secret-message")
    public Object tokenResponse() {

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        return principal;
    }

}
```

But when I opened the swagger and try to execute the rest end point with Bearer token, this Authorizaiton header is not sent as part of the request. How can we resolve this?

References
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1037
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/612

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with the latest version of swagger. But things are working fine with swagger 2.9.2

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```